# How do I send a data via curl into an mvc4 web service

Tags: c#, curl

I have a mvc web api with the following signature:
`public HttpResponseMessage Frob(string thing, [FromBody]string body)`.  The only way I've been able to get a non-null value into body, is to send data with a leading`=` sign. So when I run `curl "$server/Frob" -d '=somedata'`, it works great.

The issue comes when I want to run `curl "$server/Frob" -d '=some+data'`.  The `+` gets tranformed into a space.  No problem I say, I'll just `curl "$server/Frob" --data-urlencode '=some+data'`.  Nope, the curl docs says

```
To be CGI-compliant, the <data> part should begin with a name followed by a 
separator and a content specification. The <data> part can be passed to curl 
using one of the following syntaxes:
[...]
=content

This will make curl URL-encode the content and pass that on. 
The preceding = symbol is not included in the data.
[...]
```

I could shell out to encode the content via perl or whatever, and then prepend the `=` and send that on, but there's got to be a better way!  Do I need to make changes to the mvc web api, or is there some curl voodoo to make the `=` stay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've figured out that `curl "$server/Frob" -d '"some+data"' -H "Content-Type:application/json"` gets data into `body` since my web api accepts application/json.  Not the cleanest solution, but what I may end up going with.